# foreignObject display:none in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, svg

I have a JavaScript app that works with svg components. I have svg groups as:

```
<svg id="canvas" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1500 500">
    <g class="node-element" x="0" y="0" height="20" width="300" id="node-c87">
        <text class="node-element-text" x="12" y="15">person:object</text>    
        <image x="0" y="4" width="11" height="11" xlink:href="assets/images/object-icon.png"></image>
    </g>
    <g class="nested-group">
        <g class="node-element" x="50" y="100" height="20" width="300" id="node-c87">
            <text class="node-element-text" x="12" y="15">person:object</text>    
            <image x="0" y="4" width="11" height="11" xlink:href="assets/images/object-icon.png"></image>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

And I have defined CSS as follows(CSS on svg groups acts on all child elements of `<g>`.

```
.node-element {
    display: inline;
}
.node-element :active {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.node-element:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

The problem is that it does not work properly in Firefox, whereas it works fine in Chrome. Why and how to fix it?

The node elements are in a tree-like structure where `x` values differ based on rank. In Firefox, the hover does not properly work on the first couple of node-elements. But works fine on the rest of the node-elements, **regardless of the `x` values**.

**UPDATE:** The problem was actually caused by a foreignObject component, which I have set the elements to `display:none`. The hover was actually working on the hidden component than the desired element. It was solved by setting the display:none to the foreignObject.

But I would like to know why this was acting differently in the two browsers, Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: did you try adding a viewbox to the svg tag?

Comment: Could you provide a demo to reproduce the issue? It is working fine for me.

Comment: @pritishvaidya I added a viewPort and and nothing changed.

Comment: @Ricky_Ruiz I updated the question with more info. I'm trying to get JSfiddle to demonstrate but for some reason, svg does not work.

Comment: @SachiDangalla Could you try using the universal selector (*). Use `.node-element:hover * { opacity: 0.5; }`.

Comment: <g> elements do not support x, y, width or height attributes.

Comment: @RobertLongson yes, I use them for a different purpose.

Comment: They should be called data-x etc then. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to have all look at css `pointer-events`, documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events). With that you can specify what »region« of your graphic is used for hovers. This can be the AABB (axis aligned Bounding box, nothing or the shape of the graphic).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually caused by a foreignObject component, which I have set the elements to `display:none`. The hover was actually working on the hidden component than the desired element. It was solved by setting the `display:none` to the foreignObject.